# R Programming: Difficulty removing NAs from frame when using lapply

Tags: r, mean, lapply, na

Full disclosure: I am taking a Data Science course on Coursera. For this particular question, we need to calculate the mean of some pollutant data that is being read in from multiple files.

The main function I need help with also references a couple other functions that I wrote in the script. For brevity, I'm just going to list them and their purpose:

- boundIDs: I use this to bound the input so that inputs won't be accepted that are out of range. (range is 1:332, so if someone enters 1:400 this changes the range to 1:332)
- pollutantToCode: converts the pollutant string entered to that pollutant's column number in the data file
- fullFilePath - Creates the file name and appends it to the full file path. So if
  someone states they need the file for ID 1 in directory
  "curse/your/sudden/but/inevitable/betrayal/", the function will return
  "curse/your/sudden/but/inevitable/betrayal/001.csv" to be added to
  the file list vector.

After all that, the main function I'm working with is:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory = "", pollutant, id = 1:332){
  id <- boundIDs(id)
  pollutant <- pollutantToCode(pollutant)
  numberOfIds <- length(id)
  fileList <- character(numberOfIds)
  for (i in 1:numberOfIds){
    if (id[i] > 332){
      next
    }
    fileList[i] <- fullFilePath(directory, id[i])
  }
  data <- lapply(fileList, read.csv)
  print(data[[1]][[pollutant]])
}
```

Right now, I'm intentionally printing only the first frame of data to see what my output looks like. To remove the NAs I've tried using:

```
data <- lapply(fileList, read.csv)
data <- data[!is.na(data)]
```

But the NAs remained, so then I tried computing the mean directly and using the na.rm parameter:

```
print(mean(data[[1]][[pollutant]], na.rm = TRUE))
```

But the mean was still "NA". Then I tried na.omit:

```
data <- lapply(fileList, na.omit(read.csv))
```

...and unfortunately the problem persisted.

Can someone please help? :-/

(PS: Right now I'm just focusing on the first frame of whatever is read in, i.e. data[[1]], since I figure if I can't get it for the first frame there's no point in iterating over the rest.)

Comment: Since you gave us full disclosure I'll give it back to you.  There are a few questions in my answer list that pertain to this exact topic.  And even more than that floating around SO right now

Comment: Try `lapply(data, function(x) colMeans(x["pollutant"], na.rm = T))` or only for the first data `lapply(data[1], function(x) colMeans(x["pollutant"], na.rm = T))`

Comment: @RichardScriven - Sorry about that. I had been fruitlessly searching for the better part of half an hour on this one thing and eventually gave up. Maybe my search terms weren't the greatest...

Comment: Could also do `mean(data[[1]][["pollutant"]], na.rm = TRUE)`